# How to add listbox items through ajax in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, listbox

I want to add listbox items via ajax. I text my ajax code it's working fine. But I don't why the error occur while adding listitems.

Here is my code:

```
$('#right').click(function () {

    var item = "testing";
    $.ajax({
         url: 'ReportSalesAll.aspx/setRightListBoxitems',
         type: 'post',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         data: JSON.stringify({listItems:item}),
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (data) {
             alert("result = " + data.d);
         },
         failure: function (response) {
             alert(response.d);
         },
         error: function (error) {
             console.log("Error:", error);
         }
    });
 });

<asp:ListBox ID="FirstRight" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100%" Height="220"></asp:ListBox>
```

C# code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string setRightListBoxitems(string listItems)
{
    ReportSalesAll rs = new ReportSalesAll();

    rs.FirstRight.Items.Add(new ListItem( "Text","Text value"));  //error occuring in this line.
    //rs.FirstRight.Items.Add(listItems);
    //rs.FirstRight.Text;
    //string str=rs.FirstRight.Items[0].Text;

    //rs.FirstRight.Items[0].Value = "";
    string item = listItems;
    return listItems;
 }
```

If I keep this line `rs.FirstRight.Items.Add(new ListItem( "Text","Text value"));` error occur: Internal server error.

Thanks.

Comment: Internal server error means your server-side code is throwing errors. You can place breakpoints in you C# code to see where this error is generated

Comment: @Emad the error occur in the line where i mentioned in C# code. ` rs.FirstRight.Items.Add(new ListItem( "Text","Text value")); `.. Here What I did mistake?